# Using $resource with rest service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-resource, angularjs-resource

I'm trying to get familiar with `$resource` in order to use RESTful Web Services.

So, for the attempt, I declared a factory like this :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('BalrogApp').factory('Req', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:8000/api/catalog/requests/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
    'update': { method: 'PUT'},
    'query': { method: 'GET'}
  });
}]);
```

In my Controller I have this :

```
angular.module('BalrogApp').controller('requestsController', function(Req, $route, $rootScope, $scope, $location, $routeParams) {
  this.$route = $route;
  var controllerScope = this;

  this.r = Req.get({ id:4 });

  console.log(this.r);
```

This works fine, in my console, I can see my object with the data retrieved from the services for the item with id 4.

However I'm not sure I'm properly retrieving the data since the object i'm storing in `r` contains an id like it should in the object details (clicking on "Object" in the browser console displays the object details including its id) but the object itself (`r`) displayed on the console contains only 2 fields and is presented as follows : `Object { $promise: Object, $resolved: false }`.

So, in the end, `console.log(this.r);` works but `console.log(this.r.id);` doesn't even if `r` is supposed to contain an id just like in the object details from the browser inspector.

Also, how can I configure this service in order to be able to use `get()` with the `id` parameter just like I'm doing which results in calling `http://localhost:8000/api/catalog/requests/:id` but also without the `id` parameter which results in calling `http://localhost:8000/api/catalog/requests`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the call to the REST API is asynchronous you shout wait for the returned promise to resolve when using the `Req.get({ id:4 });`

Use:

```
Req.get({ id:4 }).$promise.then(function(result){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

instead.

For the second part of your question: Using data without an id property should be fine. This data, however, will be transfered in the request body and not as a request parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by "Using data without an id" ? I tried to replace `Req.get({ id:4 })` with `Req.get({  })` or even `Req.get()` but this didn't work.
Also could you link me where to find some doc about that `$promise`  you used ?

Comment: Not sure, but `Req.get()` or maybe `Req.get(null)` should work. Have a look at the "Return" section of the ngResource documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource for the explanation of the returned promise.

Comment: Well, with no parameter, this error fires : `Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: GET http://localhost:8000/api/catalog/requests)`. 
Doesn't `$resource('http://localhost:8000/api/catalog/requests/:id'` make `id` a mandatory field maybe ?

Comment: Apparently, I need to use `get()` when I have an `id` parameter and use `query()` when I don't to get the complete list.

Comment: The reason for this is the `isArray – {boolean=}` option of the ngResource action. It is set for the `query` action and not set for the `get` action by default. Please accept this answer if it helped you to let other people with the same kind of problem know.